# Utility jobs in Gitlab CI independent of the main pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I am coming from the background of Jenkins and Teamcity CI tools. In my new job we are looking into moving to Gitlab CI, since we already use it for other things and we don't have too many builds set up in Jenkins, so the move should not be too painful.

Gitlab CI seems well suited to the 'traditional' pipeline of `Check > Test > Stage > Deploy > Monitor`. However, we have some "utility" scripts in Jenkins which are in reality outside of the natural lifecycle. Those are usually standalone scripts to update dependencies/something, and instead of having to run them locally, a dedicated CI job is created to make it easier.

Is this possible in Gitlab CI? To have "the" pipeline and some "misc"/"util" jobs independent of that pipeline, but which work with the same repository? Is this something inconsistent with the Gitlab CI "philosophy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible once this issue is resolved: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24935

Currently aimed at Gitlab 11.10.